# What does 測る mean here?

Tags: words, usage

> 前に「知るタイミング」みたいなこと言ってましたよね、それってどうやって測ればいいんですか。

I can't understand what 測る means here. I know its dictionary definition is to measure or to weigh, but it seems to have another meaning in this sentence.

Comment: Is there any context to the sentence? Also the speaker quotes some timing so the verb most likely refers to that (but hard to say without context), are you sure it should have another meaning?

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but the context for this is that something weird is happening to a school and there is a student who doesn't have a clue about what is going on so he asked his aunt and she told him that there is a time in which he would understand everything, however something else happened at the school so he asks her again and this is what she said to him,,sorry for my bad english

Comment: It should be (タイミングを) [計]{はか}る, rather than [測]{はか}る, no?　https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%92%E8%A8%88%E3%82%8B

Comment: I think it means literally how do you measure the 知るタイミング to make it be good? (測ればいい) meaning when do you think it's a good time for me to know,but i don't know if i am right about this